# SSL Issue when accessing URL in Databricks

Tags: python, ssl, databricks, azure-databricks

I have written the below code to access external url

```
import requests

try:
    # Make an HTTPS GET request to the URL
    response = requests.get("https://www.google.com/")
    
    # Check if the response status code indicates success (2xx)
    if response.status_code // 100 == 2:
        print("Connection successful!")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to connect. Status code: {response.status_code}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Failed to connect: {e}")
```

I am getting below error :

```
Failed to connect: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1007)')))
```

How can I solve the above error as I am new to Python. If its a cert issue, in Java we can add the cert to cacerts but I am not sure about Python or Databricks.

Comment: import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

try:
    response = requests.get("https://www.google.com/", verify=False)

Comment: Can you try the above? let me know if it helped you?

Comment: Getting this error
Failed to connect: Invalid URL 'google.com': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant http://google.com?

Comment: It is unclear why the server is closing the connection, but it is unlikely that you can fix this in your program. And for sure this cannot be fixed by ignoring certificate errors. I recommend first that you check if exactly the same URL is accessible in the first place from another client on the machine, like the browser or curl.